# Break the connection between two edges by removing the minimum amount of edges

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, connectedness

We know that a drug dealer is going to deliver from city A to city B. As the police, we want to avoid the delivery. Cities are connected to other cities by roads (undirected edges). We can place one police officer in one city so it would catch the drug dealer. There are cities in which we can place police officers but there are others in which we cannot (e.g. we cannot place police officers in A nor B). We are given a set of the cities in which we can place a police officer. Is it possible to avoid the delivery? Which is the minimum amount of police officers that we need?

Mathematically speaking, we have a set of vertices R. R is the set of vertices that can be removed. And a set of vertices, N, which can not be removed(cities A and B are included). Is it possible to remove vertices from R until A is not connected to B? Which is the minimum amount of vertices we need to remove?

I am looking for some references that can help me to solve this problem. Is this a special case of any other known problem?

EDIT: I have found this [link](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/GraphTheory/MyGraphTheory/connectivity.htm). What I am looking for is similar to the vertex-cut set. But I am looking for one vertex-cut set that makes A and B not connected.

Comment: Can you please revise your question? I think that you are swapping "edge" and "cities" and it makes it confusing

Comment: anyways, your problem is most likely determining the conectivity of a graph

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991701/computing-vertex-connectivity-of-graph

Comment: This is also related:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph#Computational_complexity

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question. It was pretty bad. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Collapse your graph by identifying all vertices connected by the edges $N$ into single points (there is one such point per connected component of the subgraph $N$). This could also make some edges from $R$ 'useless' because they are reduced to loops - so eliminate these as well. If $A$ and $B$ end up being identified then we are done - no amount of police force is going to block the delivery because they can reach their destination using only the $N$ edges.

Now the problem is reduced to determining subsets of edges from $R$ that separate the component of $A$ from the component of $B$.

First construct a spanning tree for $R$ (or spanning forest if $R$ is disconnected). If $A$ and $B$ are in different components then we are done and the answer is that we need 0 police officers. Otherwise consider the unique path from $A$ to $B$ through the tree that they belong to.

Any subset of $R$ that *minimally* cuts $A$ from $B$ consists of: (1) exactly one edge on this path, and (2) all edges from $R$ that connect the two sides of the tree separated by this one edge. By 'minimal' we mean that no proper subset cuts $A$ from $B.$

Thus we are reduced to finding those choices of an edge (1) on the path for which the number of edges in (2) is minimal.

Comment: I have to apologize because my question was very badly written. I was writing edge everywhere but it was vertex instead. I am very sorry :(